# Applying same colour for same entries in 4 columns scatter matplotlib python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to color the same entries in column 4 while plotting a scatter graph (x-axis: column 1, y-axis: column 2 and 3 different in shapes). There are more than 100 rows and different entries for column4. I hope to assign an entry and its repeating entry a color.

it looks something like this:

```
column1  column2  column3  column 4
   1        3.1     7.5       a
   2        3.5     8.4       b
   3        4.6     7.3       c
   4        2.1     9.3       a
```

I am new to this and hence I am looking for some guidance.

```
plt.scatter(data["column1"], data["column2"], 'o')
plt.scatter(data["column1"], data["column3"], 'x')
plt.xlabel('column1')
plt.ylabel('column2/column3')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn is a good option:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='column1', 
                     y='column2', hue='column 4', 
                     marker='x', label='column2')
sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='column1', 
                y='column3', hue='column 4', 
                marker='o', ax=ax, label='column3')
```

Output:

[image]

You can also melt the dataframe and pass it to `sns.scatterplot`:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=data.melt(id_vars=['column1', 'column 4'],
                              value_vars=['column2','column3'], 
                              value_name='val',
                              var_name='col'),
                x='column1',
                y='val',
                hue='column 4',
                style='col')
```

which produces slightly better legend:

[image]

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. Thank you Quang Hoang, it is working now, but because my dataset requires more than different 40 colors and when I plot it, the color looks similar to the one next to it. Any idea how to resolve that?